# How to use @pytest.mark with base classes?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using py.test 2.2.4 and my testcases are organised as follows:

```python
import pytest 

class BaseTests():
    def test_base_test(self):
        pass

@pytest.mark.linuxonly
class TestLinuxOnlyLocal(BaseTests):
    pass

@pytest.mark.windowsonly
class TestWindowsOnly(BaseTests):
    pass

class TestEverywhere(BaseTests):
    pass
```

The problem with this setup is that the decorator of the first class is leaking into the second class. When I create a conftest.py as follows:

```python
import pytest
import sys 

def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    print "\n %s keywords: %s" % (item.getmodpath(), item.keywords)
    skip_message = None
    if 'windowsonly' in item.keywords and not sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        skip_message =  "Skipped: Windows only test"

    if 'linuxonly' in item.keywords and not sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        skip_message = "Skipped: Linux only test"

    if skip_message is not None:
        print skip_message
        pytest.skip(skip_message)
```

When I execute this set the output shows that the markings seems to stack up:

```
$ py.test  --capture=no
========================================== test session starts ===========================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.2.4
collected 3 items 

test_cases.py 
 TestLinuxOnlyLocal.test_base_test keywords: {'linuxonly': <MarkInfo 'linuxonly' args=() kwargs={}>, 'test_base_test': True}
.
 TestWindowsOnly.test_base_test keywords: {'linuxonly': <MarkInfo 'linuxonly' args=() kwargs={}>, 'test_base_test': True, 'windowsonly': <MarkInfo 'windowsonly' args=() kwargs={}>}
Skipped: Windows only test
s
 TestEverywhere.test_base_test keywords: {'linuxonly': <MarkInfo 'linuxonly' args=() kwargs={}>, 'test_base_test': True, 'windowsonly': <MarkInfo 'windowsonly' args=() kwargs={}>}
Skipped: Windows only test
s

================================== 1 passed, 2 skipped in 0.01 seconds ===================================
```

So I want to understand how it is possible that these markings leak between the sub-classes, and how this can be fixed/solved (the tests cases will live in the base class but the sub-classes will set up the necessary platform abstraction).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to ecatmur's good answer:  You might want to define an `pytest.mark.skipif` expression like this::

```
win32only = pytest.mark.skipif("sys.platform != 'win32'")
```

and then just decorate the win32-only tests with it::

```
@win32only
def test_something(...):
```

Another question is if you could maybe just turn the "BaseTests" into a normal test class::

```
class TestCrossPlatform:
     def test_base_tests(...):
         ...
```

i.e. avoid any inheritance?  If you then need fixtures in your tests, you can define them in your test module and accept them in the test functions (cross-platform or platform-specific ones), see [pytest fixture docs](http://pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html).  Be sure to use `pytest-2.3.5`, though, because there have been a lot of improvements especially with respect to fixtures in the `pytest-2.3` series (and more are to come with `2.4`).

Answer (score 13):

pytest takes a more function-oriented approach to testing than other Python testing frameworks (e.g. unittest), so classes are viewed mainly as a way to organise tests.

In particular, markers applied to classes (or modules) are transferred to the test functions themselves, and since a non-overridden derived class method is the same object as the base class method, this means that the marker gets applied to the base class method.

(Technical detail: currently this happens in `_pytest.python.transfer_markers()`, but don't rely on that.)

Instead of class inheritance, consider using [fixtures](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html) to encapsulate the platform-specific test setup.

---

A simpler solution might be to compare against the class name, since py.test adds the immediate containing class to item keywords:

```
if 'TestWindowsOnly' in item.keywords and not sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    skip_message =  "Skipped: Windows only test"

if 'TestLinuxOnly' in item.keywords and not sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
    skip_message = "Skipped: Linux only test"
```

Comment: Are there workarounds for this issue? I have a huge existing test suite that I'd like to migrate ot use py.test

Comment: That won't work in our case - we have a base test that >100 other tests inherit from to provide some common tests for different panels. I'll open a new question about the py.test-ish way to do this.